# Spring Security Authorization: securing parts of a webapge

Tags: spring, spring-security

Spring security provide a good way of securing pages and redirecting users to access denied pages. What I am looking to do using spring security is if a user tries to access a page A and which he is not entitled to access I want the user to stay on same page to see all the relevant menu items (the menu items gives the an idea of what they will get if they buy that entitlement) and at the same time I want to tell user that access is denied and they will need to buy that channel.

I can probably do this via `<security:authorize` tag but want to do this on a url level because of the way the content in my application is organized.

Answer (score 0):

We did something similar to this for our product

1. In the security context ,create Authentication of type RememberMeAuthenticationToken using spring library so that the user is of anonymous/remember-me type

```js
Authentication authentication = rememberMeServices.createSuccessfulAuthentication(request,
  userDetails);
```

2. Create these apis to be used in jsp page

```
public static boolean isFullyAuthenticated() {
  SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
  if (securityContext != null) {
    Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();
    return isFullyAuthenticated(authentication);
  }
  return false;

}

public static boolean isFullyAuthenticated(Authentication authentication) {
  return !authenticationTrustResolver.isAnonymous(authentication) && !authenticationTrustResolver
    .isRememberMe(authentication);
}
```

where authenticationTrustResolver is provided by spring 
AuthenticationTrustResolver authenticationTrustResolver = new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl();

3. In the jsp add the necessary checks

```html
<%if(isFullyAuthenticated()){%>
  //Menu option with links
  <%}else{%>
//menu option which shows popup/ msgs
    <%}%>
```

Note: The utility methods are explicitly written as we were not able to find security tags for rememberme/anonymous users

Comment: Thanks Amirutha, I think similar solution can be implement using the tab library provided by spring security, but again it would be something that developers can use to make it work, I was looking more from a framework's perspective on it that if there is a "right" way of doing it which is recommended by spring security.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do it implementing a custom `org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandler`. Whenever the user tries to reach a page which is not authorized to access to, it will be thrown. In the `handle` method you receive as parameter the `HttpServletRequest`, which you can use to make a kind of specific handling of each request endpoint.

```
@Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException)
                throws IOException, ServletException {

        String errorPage = doSomethingWithRequestUri(request);
        response.sendRedirect(errorPage);

    }
```

But you must be very carefull, so as if you try to redirect to the same url the user tried to enter you will fall in a infinite redirection loop. Maybe you should use a authorized/unauthorized pattern, such as this:

- /authorized/action/a
- /unauthorized/action/a

You may already have thought about this and you have achieved a solution... so that in the `AccessDeniedHandler` implementation you should just take care of the authorized/unauthorized url relations